# How to SerializeArray() HTML tags that are within a Form that also needs to be serialized?

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, contenteditable, inline-editing

I am building a form that lets users submit information to the site for publication. I am using a combination of inline editing using `contenteditable=true` on editable HTML tags, and I'm also using standard form inputs such as selects and text fields.

When the user submits the form, I want it to happen via Ajax. I understand how to serialize the form itself but I don't understand how to also serialize the HTML elements that have `contenteditable=true` set at the same time so that it all goes off in one bundle to the server.

Here is some example HTML code:

```
<form action="/path/to/server/file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--- Start WYSIWYG Inline Editing  --->
  <div id="ItemContainer">
    <h1 id="ItemTitle" contenteditable="true">A title would go here</h1>
    <h2 id="ItemSubtitle" contenteditable="true">A subtitle here</h2>
    <div id="ItemMainBody" contenteditable="true">
      <p>Integer condimentum sit amet, tempor elit odio, a dolor non ante at sapien. Sed ac lectus. Nulla ligula quis eleifend mi, id leo velit pede cursus arcu id nulla ac lectus. Phasellus vestibulum. Nunc viverra enim quis diam.</p>
      <p>Donec ullamcorper, risus tortor, pretium porttitor. Morbi quam quis lectus non leo.</p>
      <img src="/path/to/imagefile" /> 
    </div>
  </div>
<!--- End WYSIWYG Inline Editing. Standard Form elements follow... --->
  <select name="ItemCategory" id="ItemCategory">
    <option value="1">Planes</option>
    <option value="2">Trains</option>
    <option value="3">Automobiles</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="ItemURL"  id="ItemURL">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

To submit this via ajax I would do this currently:

```
('form').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/path/to/formprocessor',
            data: $('form').serializeArray(), // serializing the form
            dataType: "json",
            done: function (result) {
               // tell user its done!
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("An error has occured.");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

How do I serialize the HTML elements as well so that everything gets submitted together? I'd like the ID of the contenteditable element to represent its name. So in the POST I would like to see:

```
ItemCategory    1
ItemTitle   A title would go here
ItemSubtitle A subtitle here
ItemURL http://www.com
ItemMainBody <p>Integer condimentum sit amet, tempor elit odio, a dolor non ante at sapien. Sed ac lectus. Nulla ligula quis eleifend mi, id leo velit pede cursus arcu id nulla ac lectus. Phasellus vestibulum. Nunc viverra enim quis diam.</p>
      <p>Donec ullamcorper, risus tortor, pretium porttitor. Morbi quam quis lectus non leo.</p>
      <img src="/path/to/imagefile" />
```

Comment: Would `ItemURL` value be url of page form is loaded from ?

Comment: @guest271314 no its just a link to that item on an external site. it may be left empty by the user.

Comment: `value` attribute not appear at that element ?

Comment: @guest271314 `ItemURL` is part of the Form input element. It can be left blank by the user but it may also have a URL in it. This field is just letting the user enter in a link to where that item can be found. It has no impact on how the form itself functions.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you would have to manually add the parameters into the array before submitting, here is the JS code:

```js
('form').submit(function(e) {
  var formToSubmit = e.target;
  var serialisedFormArrayObject = $(formToSubmit).serializeArray();
  var $contentEditableItems = $("[contenteditable=true]");
  $contentEditableItems.each(function(index) {
    serialisedFormArrayObject.push({
      name: $contentEditableItems[index].id,
      value: $contentEditableItems[index].innerHTML
    });
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/path/to/formprocessor',
    data: serialisedFormArrayObject,
    dataType: "json",
    done: function(result) {
      // tell user its done!
    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert("An error has occured.");
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

- Edited to answer the actual question after clarification, though the below information may still be useful to others.

In order to escape an html string you would need to use the built in Javascript method encodeURIComponent. So for example, if you have:

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent("<div>potato</div>"));
```

You will get : %3Cdiv%3Epotato%3C%2Fdiv%3E
Depending on the language you are using on the server side, you can then decode it back.

Be careful of allowing users to input the `script` tag as this can lead to [Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

So you would need to change the line

> data: $(this).serializeArray(), // serializing the form

To

```
data: encodeURIComponent($(this).serializeArray()), // serializing the form
```

Lastly, if you want the form submitted as a query string, instead of as form content, you will need to set the verb to a GET instead of POST

Comment: Sereph I've adjusted my question. I think I misunderstood the output.

Comment: I just want to add for anyone else reading this that SerializeArray() does not include the input submit button. You have to add this yourself doing a push()

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("form").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ItemURL").val(location.href);
    var res = $(this).serializeArray(); // serializing the form
    // `serialize` `ItemContainer` elements to `{name:value}` pairs
    $("#ItemContainer *[id^=Item]")
    .each(function(i, el) {
        var j = {};
        j.name = el.id;
        j.value = $.trim(el.innerHTML);
        res.push(j)
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {json:JSON.stringify(res)}, 
        dataType: "json",
        // substitute `success` for `done` _within_ `ajaxSettings` ,
        // utilize `.done` or `.then` _after_ , 
        // i.e.g., `$.ajax({}).done()` , `$.ajax({}).then()`
        success: function (result) {  
                // tell user its done!
                $("pre").text(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))                   
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("An error has occured.");
            }
        });
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3zn4Lbab/